# Mute on/off function on single button

Tags: vb.net

I have a music playing in the background.

I can stop the music with the following code:

```
    Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles audio.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
    End Sub
```

But I can not restart or resume it.

So, can single button be assigned mute on/off (or start/stop) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable for this. Try the following technique :

```
Dim IsAudioPlaying As Boolean = True

Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles audio.Click
    If IsAudioPlaying Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
        IsAudioPlaying = False
    Else
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(Nothing)
        IsAudioPlaying = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I got two error; "Bool type is not defined" and "Start is not an Audio member."

Comment: Please Check now.

Comment: See the full code please, there is no Bool now!
`Dim IsAudioPlaying As Boolean = True`

Comment: ups sorry, I was forget the copy Dim :) its okay now but when I press again exe is crashing. So I changed "My.Computer.Audio.Play(Nothing)" to "My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.backgrounds, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)" it works properly, thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear that your problem is sorted out.